# What should I do to load all-mpnet-base-v2 model from sentence-transformers?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I am trying to run `all-mpnet-base-v2` model with `sentence-transformers` 1.2.1 from my Anaconda framework (in Python 3.8). My first prompt for the model is like this:

```
bert_model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')
```

However, when I run this model, after downloading the model from the internet Anaconda returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 115, in __init__
    module = module_class.load(os.path.join(model_path, module_config['path']))
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py", line 115, in load
    return Transformer(model_name_or_path=input_path, **config)
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py", line 29, in __init__
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, **model_args, cache_dir=cache_dir)
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_auto.py", line 275, in from_pretrained
    config_class = CONFIG_MAPPING[config_dict["model_type"]]
KeyError: 'mpnet
```

'
I have tried another prompt with the direct link to `all-mpnet-base-v2` like this:

```
 bert_model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2')
```

However, this time Anaconda tried to go to the download link, and I get this error:

```
Exception when trying to download http://sbert.net/models/sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2.zip. Response 404
SentenceTransformer-Model http://sbert.net/models/sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2.zip not found. Try to create it from scratch
Try to create Transformer Model sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2 with mean pooling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 79, in __init__
    http_get(model_url, zip_save_path)
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\util.py", line 242, in http_get
    req.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reimers/sentence-transformers/v0.2/sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2.zip
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 353, in get_config_dict
    raise EnvironmentError
OSError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 95, in __init__
        transformer_model = Transformer(model_name_or_path)
      File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py", line 29, in __init__
        config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, **model_args, cache_dir=cache_dir)
      File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_auto.py", line 272, in from_pretrained
        config_dict, _ = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 362, in get_config_dict
        raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    OSError: Can't load config for 'sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2'. Make sure that:
    
    - 'sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
    
    - or 'sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
`
```

So, what should I do to get `all-mpnet-base-v2` running with Anaconda?

Comment: Please post the output of: `import transformers
import sentence_transformers
print(transformers.__version__)
print(sentence_transformers.__version__)` You probably need to upgrade transformers.